# Attribute Error for Usage of Python Email Import

Tags: python, email

```
    def ExtractBody(self, msg):
        content = ""
        if msg.is_multipart():
            for payload in msg.get_payload():
                content += str(payload.get_payload())
        else:
            content += str(msg.get_payload())
        return content
```

Hello everyone, with the code above, I was trying to extract the body of a .eml file from a class, but when I used the code above, it gives me the error as shown below.

Why is this so, and how can I fix it?

For extra information, I am getting this email from a web server that makes use of flask.

```
<class 'AttributeError'>
'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: what is the value of msg? What line has the error?

Comment: Hi there, I've done some checking, and from what I've been able to see, it is from the content+=str(payload.get_payload()) line that gives me the error, additionally, the error only occurs after 1 or 2 iterations of the for loop. The value of msg comes from an extracted email using the email.message_from_bytes() method.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I have a temporary fix to the problem

I am not sure why, but when I shifted the method from the class to the .py file itself, the code now works.